# If checkbox is checked, get the next input[text]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to `('.hidden-textbox').css('visibility', 'visible')` for input's that are `checked`. For example, Question 1, Question 4, and Question 5 should have **their** input textbox (.hidden-textbox) set to `visible`. How can I do that in jQuery and javascript?

I have some code like this:

```
<style>
.hidden-textbox {
    visibility: hidden;
}
</style>

<div class="question">Question 1: <input type="checkbox" checked><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
<div class="question">Question 2: <input type="checkbox"><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
<div class="question">Question 3: <input type="checkbox"><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
<div class="question">Question 4: <input type="checkbox" checked><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
<div class="question">Question 5: <input type="checkbox" checked><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done using only css

In this snippet it will select a checkbox which is checked then it sibling class
& will set the visibility

```
input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .hidden-textbox{
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```css
.hidden-textbox {
  visibility: hidden;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked~.hidden-textbox {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="question">Question 1: <input type="checkbox" checked><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
<div class="question">Question 2: <input type="checkbox"><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
<div class="question">Question 3: <input type="checkbox"><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
<div class="question">Question 4: <input type="checkbox" checked><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
<div class="question">Question 5: <input type="checkbox" checked><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
```

Comment: is that an `if` condition in CSS?

Comment: `:` is a pseudo selector & `~` is a selector

Comment: how do I make the visible textboxes have a value of "test"?

Comment: Try by changing the attribute selector.[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) is the link

Comment: i don't know which one to use. Can you even change the value of a textbox using CSS? I was thinking jquery `.val()`

Comment: I will help you but before that you have to give a try and investigate the problem .This will be helpful for you.no offence meant.

Comment: no worries. I tried this but it did not work: `input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .hidden-textbox:after {
    content: "Test";
   }`

Comment: So you want to set the value to `test` once it is visible?

Comment: Yes only text boxes that are visible should have a value of "Test"

Comment: Why don't you test the value through html? like this `<input type="text" class="hidden-textbox" value = "test"></div>`

Comment: because when it is a part of the form. When it is submitted, only the input's that have a check next to them should have a value "test" assigned to it. Is it possible to use Javascript/jquery to achieve this?

Comment: i'm using jquery to accomplish this now: $(".hidden-textbox").each(function() {
        if($(this).css("visibility") == "visible") {
            $(this).val('test');
        }
    });

Answer (score 1):

## Selecting Checked Checkboxes

This can be done in Javascript by adding `:checked` to your selector will filter for checked checkboxes in your selection, like so:

```js
var checkedCheckboxes = $("checkbox:checked");
```

Comment: how do I make the visible textboxes have a value of "test"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the :checked and adjacent sibling selectors to accomplish your goal. As such:

```css
.hidden-textbox {
  visibility: hidden;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked + input {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="question">Question 1: <input type="checkbox" checked><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
<div class="question">Question 2: <input type="checkbox"><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
<div class="question">Question 3: <input type="checkbox"><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
<div class="question">Question 4: <input type="checkbox" checked><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
<div class="question">Question 5: <input type="checkbox" checked><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
```

Comment: how do I make the visible textboxes have a value of "test"?

Comment: You'll need to add javascript to add/remove the attribute on textbox change $("input[type=text]").on('change') using the attribute setter textbox.attr("value", "test") and remover textbox.removeAttr("value")

Answer (score 1):

To check if the checkbox is checked or not you need `$(this).prop('checked')== true`.

```js
$('input:checkbox').each(function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked')== true) {
    $(this).next('input').val('test');
    $(this).next('input').show();
  } else  {
    $(this).next('input').hide();
  }
});

$('input:checkbox').on('click', function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked')== true) {
    $(this).next('input').val('test');
    $(this).next('input').show();
  } else  {
    $(this).next('input').hide();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">Question 1: <input type="checkbox" checked><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
<div class="question">Question 2: <input type="checkbox"><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
<div class="question">Question 3: <input type="checkbox"><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
<div class="question">Question 4: <input type="checkbox" checked><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
<div class="question">Question 5: <input type="checkbox" checked><input type="text" class="hidden-textbox"></div>
```

Comment: how do I make the visible textboxes have a value of "test"?

Comment: @pixie123 updated. you need `$(this).next('input').val('test');` when check box is checked i.e true.

Answer (score 0):

By jquery you can do this also :

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  $(this).next().find('input').toggle()
})
```

Here is an example : 
https://jsfiddle.net/99u4mwee/2/